# Using Kotlin's Android resource extensions using Maven only

Tags: android, maven, maven-3, kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

I'd like to use the [Kotlin Android extensions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) in my Maven-based project, but despite adding `kotlin-android-extensions` to my set of Maven plugins, it just doesn't take.

My, I think fairly minimal, setup is the following:

```
.
├── AndroidManifest.xml
├── pom.xml
├── res
│   └── layout
│       └── main_activity.xml
└── src
    └── activity.kt
```

## `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.KotlinAndroid"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="0.1-SNAPSHOT">
  <uses-sdk
      android:minSdkVersion="14"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />  
  <application android:label="Hello Kotlin">    
    <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>   
  </application>
</manifest>
```

## `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example.KotlinAndroid</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello-kotlin</artifactId>
  <packaging>apk</packaging>
  <name>hello-kotlin</name>
  <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>    
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
      <artifactId>android</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.1.4</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>   
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
      <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>    
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <sdk>
            <platform>19</platform>
          </sdk>
          <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
        </configuration>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
      </plugin>      
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <phase>process-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>         
          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <phase>process-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-android</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-android-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- I needed to add this plugin otherwise my Kotlin source
           files are not found -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <version>1.10</version>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals><goal>add-source</goal></goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>      
    </plugins>
  </build>  
</project>
```

## `res/layout/main_activity.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>    
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:text="Hello World!"
      android:id="@+id/textView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

## `src/activity.kt`:

```
package com.example.KotlinAndroid.activity

import android.os.Bundle
import android.app.Activity
import com.example.KotlinAndroid.R

class MainActivity() : Activity() {

    protected override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState : Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity)
    }
}
```

So this all works until I change `activity.kt` to import `kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.main_activity.*` instead of `import com.example.KotlinAndroid.R`, which then fails with

> - [ERROR] `hello-kotlin/src/activity.kt`: (6, 8)
>     Unresolved reference: `kotlinx`
> - [ERROR] `hello-kotlin/src/activity.kt`: (12, 24)
>     Unresolved reference: `R`

All the solutions to this problem that I've found apply only to Gradle builds, in which case apparently adding the `kotlin-android-extensions` plugin is enough. However, in my Maven-only build, I already have `kotlin-android-extensions` in my list of plugins (see the `pom.xml` file); and yet Kotlin doesn't generate the required `kotlinx.*` classes.

Comment: I should also add that what you see is what I got: I'm not using any IDEs. This is my full source tree, and I'm running `mvn3 package` to generate my APK file.

Comment: You probably need to add it to some lifecycle goal, so it knows when to execute.  Given that Android pushes the idea of Gradle, you may be going a bit against the grain here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kotlin-android-extensions is now a part of kotlin-gradle plugin. kotlin-maven plugin doesn't support android at all now. There is an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/KT-4533) in your tracker that you can vote for.

Comment: I would really like to use Maven for building my kotlin android project.